# Product measure on R^2

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

$\int_{]a_1, b_1] \times ]a_2, b_2]} f \, d\lambda^2 = \int_{a_2}^{b_2} \int_{a_1}^{b_1} f(x_1, x_2) \, dx_1 \, dx_2$

f is continous function from R^2 to R. I have to show the equation above. My question is: isnt this Fubinis theorem or can i apply fubini on the LHS?

Comment: It is a special case of Fubini. You just have to know that continuity implies measurability and integrability.

Comment: I know that. But still I don't know what to show.

Comment: Ask your teacher. My guess is that you are not allowed to use Fubini, since you are asked to prove it in this special case.